# How to prevent or block app usage by users using old versions of app?

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to ensure that users of my app are always using the latest version. If they haven't updated the app to the latest version, I would like to prevent them from using the app.

What is the best way to do this ? In each activity I can check my apps website to see what the latest version should be, and compare it with the device,but it seems clunky.

Isn't there a better way to display some kind of UI that prevents the user  from using any of the other activities ?

Comment: Initialize a variable in your "Application" class with your latest version from your website and then compare it on all your activities by device's version or redirect user to a placeholder activity which shows notification about update.

Comment: Right my question is what is the best way to redirect to a placeholder activity that prevents accessing any of the other activities.... as in I understand how to check the website etc, but how to create and show an activity, that prevents the user from accessing other activities...

Answer (score 2):

in Splash Activity check last number version release from server, if number version Server bigger of BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE, user need update app, you can show dialog and dialog.setCancelable(false).

Comment: Will this prevent them from using the app if it has already been opened before ?

Comment: you can push by firebase all user and handle this (notification user update new release and in code  show dialog)

Answer (score 0):

Have a local string that you change every update and have a string on a server that you also change when you update. Then every app open compare local to server. E.G.
Someone hasn't updated the app
Local string is 1.11
Server string is 1.14
Compare them and since they aren't the same, do something to block usage.

Comment: Thanks, but that is my question! How do I block the usage ? Is there a way to create an activity that that I launch when I detect this, that prevents the use from accessing any of the other activities?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Rasoul Miri compare the BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE with your version value saved on server and if it doesnt match then open an activity which shows information about update of your app and override the onBackPressed() method of that activity and enter this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    System.exit(0); // Kill the app
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution for this is to check BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE and compare it with the version code in the server. Add an alert dialog and redirect it Playstore update screen on the Alert positive response button, and override the `onBackPressed()` method if the user tries to do anything else. This will force them to update to latest version of the application.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    System.exit(0); // Kill the app
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```